# Printing all the value of perfect squares before the inputted number

Tags: python, loops

```
number = int(input("Please enter a positive number? "))
if number >= 0:
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        perfect_squares = i**2
        print(perfect_squares, end=" ")
elif number < 0:
    print("Error: you entered a negative number")
```

If I input the number 10 for example, I want it to output "1 4 9" right now it is outputting all of the perfect squares from 1 to 10.

How to a end the loop to only do the numbers up to the inputted number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the range to stop at square root of the number user entered:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a positive number? "))
if number >= 0:
    for i in range(1, int(number ** 0.5 + 1)):
        perfect_squares = i**2
        print(perfect_squares, end=" ")
elif number < 0:
    print("Error: you entered a negative number")
```

Output:

```
Please enter a positive number? 10
1 4 9
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
number = int(input("Please enter a positive number? "))
if number >= 0:
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    perfect_squares = i**2
    print(perfect_squares, end=" ")
    if perfect_squares > i:  # add if statement here
        break
elif number < 0:
    print("Error: you entered a negative number")
```